# The term 'Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have problem with last task, assign policy:

[image]

Module **AzureRM** which contains Resources namespace (with Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition) should be already included, right?
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources/help/Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition.md

So why I have this error message?

> The term 'Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image]

When I add to PowerShell task line:

> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
>
> Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.6.2 -Force -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
>
> Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Resources -RequiredVersion 6.7.3 -Force -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber

Then I will at the end get:

> Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

How to deal with that problem?

```
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1108266Z ##[section]Starting: Assign Azure Policy
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1190930Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191016Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191088Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191160Z Version      : 4.159.7
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191219Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191280Z Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
2020-01-23T12:42:46.1191368Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-23T12:42:48.5385840Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_3.1.0\Az.Accounts\1.6.4\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2020-01-23T12:42:50.3192937Z ##[warning]Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
2020-01-23T12:42:55.2184342Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2020-01-23T12:42:56.2685211Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2020-01-23T12:42:56.8285933Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud
2020-01-23T12:42:57.9191448Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 78afced4-1c58-4e66-8242-c042890d34c3 -TenantId ***
2020-01-23T12:42:58.5652039Z ##[command]& 'D:\a\_temp\743dfd85-b908-48ee-9a00-e0ee97b44c8a.ps1' 
2020-01-23T12:42:59.9241324Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-01-23T12:43:00.1484807Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-01-23T12:43:00.6509257Z ##[error]Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
2020-01-23T12:43:00.6856188Z ##[section]Finishing: Assign Azure Policy
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning in your log has display the issue caused:

> Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and
>   AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the
>   same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an
>   environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to
>   remove all AzureRm modules from your machine....

Not sure what is your scripts in your previous tasks. But based on this error message, what I can sure is it installed the `AzureRm` module into the workspace. And as a result, `AzureRM` module has conflict with `Az` module in later steps.

`Az` module is the new module which we develope and used to replace the `AzureRm` module. But when you install the `AzureRm` and `Az` module into one workspace, it easily cause [conflict](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-new-azure-powershell-az-module/) which will lead the error.

---

There's no error on your scripts shared, so just need run `Uninstall-AzureRm` before your scripts to avoid this cmdlet conflicts.

Comment: You right, those modules cannot be both installed. Also I want to share info how I solved that problem: I fiound a relpacment for missing commands (for task Assign Policy v4) and use ` Get-AzPolicyDefinition`(instead of Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition` and `New-AzPolicyAssignment -AssignIdentity -Location locationName` instead of `New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment ` to get this working properly.

Comment: @Gajush, Great to know you found the replacement! I saw these replacement commands are all belong to Az module. Appreciate you share the method you used to solved as answer here:-)

Comment: Great work ... gone through many documents and website .. but not use ... you short explanation, explains more that anyone ... Thanks ...